# How I can sync animations in Table View with Swift

Tags: swift, core-animation

I have a table view with animation in each cell, the animation is a circle blinking but when made scroll the new row blink in different time. The idea is all circles blink at same time.

Thanks by any help. I had 2 days try different things. The last is make my own animation with a timer and save the time in global variable. But i think that core animation should have something for do that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myClassCell", for: indexPath) as! MyClassCell

    cell.circleBlinking.alpha = 0

    View.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction, .curveLinear], animations: {
        cell.circleBlinking.alpha = 1} )
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you tried and what went wrong, did you  get an error?

Comment: Already put the code, really is simple, that worked. The circle blink but when I make scrolling the new cells that are showing have other time in the blink.  I will put an example in Github.

Comment: I created this project with the case. https://github.com/wilmanro77/TableViewWithAnimationInCells

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://medium.com/itch-design-no/syncing-uiview-animations-57659ec3c41e

Comment: Already saw that and the scenario is not the same. My main problem is because when I do scrolling the row that are not visible are drawing just in the moment that are visible, If I could know the current frame o time of the first animation and say to my new animation that with what frame start. I would fix it. But i don't know how do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for the requirement. I made the animation with a timer.

1. I created a global timer that change a global variable each 1/24 secs from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0
2. When pass by cellForRowAt I create other timer just for that cell but the function is just give the value alpha from my global variable that is doing modified by the main timer. So that way I have all circles sync

If somebody know how do that with animate welcome with your answer.

Already I uploaded the code to Github with solution.

https://github.com/wilmanro77/TableViewWithAnimationInCells